# Javascript, pass-by-value an object to a constructor

Tags: javascript, pass-by-value

I'm developing a game using Node.js ; I have a Bot class containing a `position` attribute and a `fire` method. This method acts as follow:

```
Bot.prototype.fire = function () {
    this.bombs.push(new Bomb(this.position));
};
```

Obviously, the bomb's position has to differ from the bot's position, so I want `this.position` to be copied into my new Bomb object.
But in this case, the object is passed to the constructor by reference and not by value, so that if I write `this.position = position` in Bomb's constructor, the game will not work.

Now my question is pretty straightforward : is there a **simple** way (I don't want to define a new function just for that) to pass the `position` object by value instead of by reference? Or am I forced to write something like this in Bomb's constructor :

```
this.position = {
    x: position.x,
    y: position.y,
    angle: position.angle
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Everything is pass-by-value in JavaScript, just like Java. "Objects" are not values in JavaScript and cannot be "passed". `position` is a pointer to an object, not an object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an object by reference. But you can clone an object before you pass it. The simplest is to use `Object.create()`:

```
Bot.prototype.fire = function () {
    this.bombs.push(new Bomb(Object.create(this.position)));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can easy copy objects by values.

```
var obj = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'};

var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, obj);
```

You can also deep copy (slow, recursion) with `true` as first argument.

```
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.create`:

```
this.bombs.push(new Bomb(Object.create(this.position)));
```